# Unity create a moving pattern background

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

i am new to unity and need some help regarding creating a background that will look something like this (A bit jittery because its a gif), i want it to be like fill every screen size and have size 1/8th of the screen (the black box): [image]

[image: box]

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @derHugo I want to create a background that looks like the gif i posted above but i don't know how can i do it (sorry for bad english i don't know much)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following setup:

1. First the image should have borders like this one and set its Wrap mode to reapeat in the [import settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)

[image]

2. Your background should be a `ScreenSpace Overlay` Canvas (depends on your setup ofcourse)
3. Within that Canvas have a `RawImage` object, use your image as Texture and add this component to it

   ```c#
   [RequireComponent(typeof(RawImage))]
   public class BackgroundController : MonoBehaviour
   {
       [Header("References")]
       [SerializeField] private RectTransform _rectTransform;
       [SerializeField] private RectTransform _parentRectTransform;
       [SerializeField] private RawImage _image;
       [Header("Settings")]
       [SerializeField] private Vector2 repeatCount;
       [SerializeField] private Vector2 scroll;
       [SerializeField] private Vector2 offset;

       private void Awake()
       {
           if (!_image) _image = GetComponent<RawImage>();

           _image.uvRect = new Rect(offset, repeatCount);
       }

       // Start is called before the first frame update
       private void Start()
       {
           if (!_rectTransform) _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
           if (!_parentRectTransform) _parentRectTransform = GetComponentInParent<RectTransform>();

           SetScale();
       }

       // Update is called once per frame
       private void Update()
       {
   #if UNITY_EDITOR
           // Only done in the Unity editor since later it is unlikely that your screensize changes
           SetScale();
   #endif
           offset += scroll * Time.deltaTime;
           _image.uvRect = new Rect(offset, repeatCount);
       }

       private void SetScale()
       {
           // get the diagonal size of the screen since the parent is the Canvas with
           // ScreenSpace overlay it is always fiting the screensize
           var parentCorners = new Vector3[4];
           _parentRectTransform.GetLocalCorners(parentCorners);
           var diagonal = Vector3.Distance(parentCorners[0], parentCorners[2]);

           // set width and height to at least the diagonal
           _rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(diagonal, diagonal);
       }
   }
   ```

This first scales the `RawImage` to fit the diagonal size of the parent. Since it is already fitting the screen this gets us the screen sizes => always fills the entire screen, no matter what the scales or rotation are (as long as your RawImage is on the center of the screen ofcourse).

Using the `repeatCount` you define how often the texture should be on the background.

Then using the `scroll` you can define how fast and in which direction the background should scroll. The script basically simply updates the [`RawImage.uvRect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage-uvRect.html) every frame.

Finally you simply rotate the `RawImage` so the scroll goes in the final direction you want

[image]

---

Note that there is certainly also a pure shader based solution to this as also within shaders you have access to the time variables. I'm not a shader expert though ^^

Comment: Hmm if he uses screen space he will have a problem that this will cover any 3D cameras rendering if I'm not mistaken. Also, wouldn't it be simpler to use a quad and use the built in `Tiling/Offset` properties of the shader, and just animating the values? (obviously keeping the texture on `Repeat`)

Comment: shure you can go this way as well, you would however actually simply render the background with another camera and render everything else on top ;)
I don't know if it is now more efficient to use this or to set shader values every frame. Having a very broad question I honestly didn't put too deep thoughts into the answer ;)

Comment: @derHugo Hi thanks for your answer but i only get a white screen when i play it.

Comment: Did you put your image into the RawImage as texture?

Comment: @derHugo Yes sir i did the following  ->  Hierarchy panel -> UI > Raw Image > Create a script that you gave > drag drop into component > then have rect transform selected rawimage and parent rect as canvas, and yes i drag dropped image you provided into texture but all i see is a white screen and no change in values after playing :(

Comment: @derHugo I tried again and i got this : https://gofile.io/?c=gf2GES

Comment: set the **`repeatCount`** and later **`scroll`** as I described and showed in my gif ;) `0,0` means the texture will be there 0 times ... so it stays blanc

Comment: I think you need to check the import settings. You must set the Wrap Mode as a 'Repeat' and set the sprite mode as a 'Single'. It should be work.

Answer (score 0):

So you want some kind of infinity scrolling background?

Here is some simple way to create it.

1) You will need *tilable image* (that can be connected one side to other seamlessly). You can use one frame from your gif. Add it to your assets (just drag and drop it there).

2) In your Unity scene create new Quad object (**GameObject->3d Object->Quad**)

3) Drag and drop your image from your assets window right onto your Quad. That will apply texture to it.

4) Create simple script on your Quad object. I called mine RollerScript

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class RollerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 2f;
    public MeshRenderer renderer;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(Time.time * speed, Time.time * speed);
        renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = offset;
    }
}
```

5) Go back to Editor and assign renderer field (drag your Quad object from Hierarchy to that field)

6) Hit **Play** and adjust speed parameter in your script editor window. Your texture will scroll diagonally to right-top (as on your gif). If you want another direction you can change this line:

```
Vector2 offset = new Vector2(Time.time * speed, Time.time * speed);
```

Set x or y value of Vector2 to zero if you want NO scrolling horizontaly/vertically. Change x or y value to -x or -y if you want to scroll in opposite direction.